# Revision history: Duplicate message has wrong cursor

Tags: bug, design, revision-history

when looking at the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1801391/revisions) of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801391/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-checking-if-a-number-is-prime) question I noticed that my cursor changes to a cross-hair cursor when hovering the line duplicate link is in but not the duplicate link itself (after rev 2):

[image]

Answer (score 16):

This is caused by the following CSS rule:

```css
.originals-of-duplicate li {
  cursor: move
}
```

which is part of a recent feature that [allows users with moderation privileges to rearrange duplicate links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291824/gold-tag-badge-holders-and-moderators-can-now-edit-duplicate-links). Ostensibly, this CSS rule is leaking into the revision history where it doesn't belong, and something needs to be changed, be it the class name(s) being used, or the selector.

Comment: Shouldn't there be added a class to body/html `.has-moderation-privilege` and the selector be changed to `.has-moderation-privilege .originals-of-duplicate li`?

Comment: @MEE: No, because the rule needs to not apply to the revision history altogether, since that's not where editing duplicates happens. It happens on a separate page that can only be seen by users with the requisite privileges.

Comment: I am still able to reproduce this issue. Do you know whether an update/fix is planned?